# Emoticons MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

While making my project I stuck on a problem.

I have the following thing:
This is in my PostComment action

```
comment = Emoticon.Format(comment);
```

Emoticon is public class.
The Format action return the following:

```
public static string Format(string input)
    {
        if (input == null || input.Length == 0)
        {
            return input;
        }
        else
        {
            string result = input;

            Emoticon[] all = All;
            foreach (Emoticon emoticon in all)
            {
                string a;
                string a_;
                int border;

                // Decide whether a link is required.
                if (emoticon.Url != null && emoticon.Url.Length > 0)
                {
                    a = string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\">", emoticon.Url);
                    a_ = "</a>";
                    border = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    a = "";
                    a_ = "";
                    border = 0;
                }

                // Replace this emoticon.
                string replacement =
                    string.Format(
                    "{0}<img src=\"{1}\" alt=\"{2}\" align=\"AbsMiddle\" border=\"{3}\" />{4}",
                    a,
                    emoticon.VirtualPath,
                    HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(emoticon.Title),
                    border,
                    a_);

                result = result.Replace(emoticon.Shortcut, replacement);
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

And from PostComment action I go to view and print the comment:

```
<div class="panel-body">@comment.Content</div>
```

But my problem is in `string.Format(
"{0}<img src=\"{1}\" alt=\"{2}\" align=\"AbsMiddle\" border=\"{3}\" />{4}",` because it returns string and in the view it is a string but my purpose is to be a picture. `@comment.Comment` is also string.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. How do you expect a string to be a picture?

Comment: You mean the html code is rendered in your view instead of an image?

Comment: if the html is being displayed as text instead of the actual image, try 
`<div class="panel-body">@Html.Raw(comment.Content)</div>`

Comment: thank you adiga it works now!